# Datasheet View Lookup on Calculated Column String;#

Tags: 2010, microsoft-access

Found many posts on the internet but none adressing this scenario:

The machine has Office 2010 64bit, which means that "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" had to be installed in order to work with SharePoint Datasheet View:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

But then there is this problem with lookup columns on a list pointing to calculated columns on other list that every value on the field will start with "string;#" followed by the actual values on tha calculated column.

This is a known bug for which there is this hotfix:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948952/en-us

Problem is the hotfix does not apply for people with just the Data connectivity components referred above.

Anyone knows of some other fix, or will I have to workaround with a workflow/event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much looking around got to the conclusion that no fix matches this situation and a workaround should be applied.